# What are the use cases of using the Static variable and Instance variables in apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have read from various different sites about the static and instance variables but I am not able to understand when to use Static and when instance in the class.
I need to know the use cases of both type of variables according to the real world requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store information that is shared across instances of a class, use a static variable.

Instance variables are used by an instance of a class, i.e., by an object. An instance member variable is declared inside a class, but not within a method

Check the link for examples :
https://gvallejos.com/static-and-instance-in-apex-salesforce/